# How to vertical align 2 elements in this scenario?

Tags: html, css, alignment, vertical-alignment

I have 2 elements, a title and an icon contained in a card.

Title is center aligned horizontally and icon is right aligned horizontally.

But now I want to vertically align both items in the middle.

```
<div class='card center-align'>
  <span class='card-title'>Title</span>
  <i class='material-icons right'>delete</i>
</div>

.card {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/mn3Ldyc7/4/

Been pulling my hair out trying out different methods, but still can't get it perfectly aligned. Any help greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution using flex :

```css
.card {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.card-title {
  flex: 1
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/1e005331dc.js"></script>
<div class='card center-align'>
  <span class='card-title'>Title</span>
  <i class='material-icons right'>delete</i>
</div>
```

Comment: love this flexbox solution. I was trying it before but looks like i forgot to add flex: 1 to the card-title. thanks!

Comment: @JosephLiu yes, the flex:1 will make the title take the remain space and delete take only the necessary space for its content ;)

Answer (score 2):

Give `display: table-cell;` to `.card` class.

```css
.card {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}
.card .card-title {  
  line-height: 30px;
}
i.right {
  line-height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/1e005331dc.js"></script>

<div class='card center-align'>
  <span class='card-title'>Title</span>
  <i class='material-icons right'>delete</i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just apply the `line-height` to your span and icon.

```css
.card {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
}

.card > span.card-title, i.right{
  line-height: 90px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/1e005331dc.js"></script>

<div class='card center-align'>
  <span class='card-title'>Title</span>
  <i class='material-icons right'>delete</i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution is to give the items in the .card div a line-height the same size of the div.

```css
.card {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.card * {
  line-height: 100px !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/1e005331dc.js"></script>

<div class='card center-align'>
  <span class='card-title'>Title</span>
  <i class='material-icons right'>delete</i>
</div>
```

Note that I had to include `!important`, which wasn't by choice, but the snippet puts the googleapis link in after my own css.

Comment: maybe you can change your selector to be more specific and then avoid the !important :)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple possible answers here, let's go with the quick one;

```
.card {
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
}
```

**But...**

… the drawback is, that if your text ever goes beyond one line in your card, your layout breaks. Better solution, using flexbox:

```css
.card {
  width: 500px;
  min-height: 100px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}

.card-title {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
          flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class='card center-align'>
  <span class='card-title'>Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Curabitur blandit tempus</span>
  <i class='material-icons right'>delete</i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can help you.

https://jsfiddle.net/devefrontend/mn3Ldyc7/7/

```
<div class="ds-table">
  <div class="ds-table-cell">
   <span class='card-title'>Title</span>
   <i class='material-icons right'>delete</i>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.card {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
}
.ds-table {
  display:table;
  text-align:center;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.ds-table-cell {
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/1e005331dc.js"></script>

    <div class='card'>
  <div class="ds-table">
    <div class="ds-table-cell">
      <span class='card-title'>Title</span>
      <i class='material-icons right'>delete</i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```